# How to share MDC context between threads in multimodule project in kotlin - kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, slf4j, mdc, withcontext

I have a multi-module project where I would like to have a context to be shared through the different modules.

In my core module (from which all of them depends on), I have created a class to manage the context using org.slf4j.MDC with two functions, one to store properties in the context (logContext) and another one to get the context (getContext)

```
import jakarta.inject.Singleton
import kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j.MDCContextMap
import mu.KotlinLogging
import org.slf4j.MDC

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

@Singleton
class LoggingContext {
    companion object {
        fun logContext(name: String, id: String) {
            MDC.put("name", name)
            MDC.put("id", id)
            logger.info { "Companion object - logContext: ${MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()}" }
        }

        fun getContext(): MDCContextMap {
            logger.info { "Companion object - getContext: ${MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()}" }
            return MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is as follow:

I have a full module where I have a controller and I want to store the `name` and `id` that is coming from the request in the context. For that, I just add the following line in my controller code:

```
logContext("request_name", "request_id")
```

Within the controller code (in the controller module), if I invoke the `getContext()` function I'm getting the properties that I just saved from the request. Until here everything's fine ✅

❌ But, if I tried to do the same, get the context from another module, for example, invoke the `getContext()` function from the repository module (it is a fully new module within the project) I'm getting a null. There is no context at all.

I'm assuming is because, when I tried to get the context from another module, it is other thread and the context is not shared within the whole project.

**UPDATE**: to give more context, the flow is as follow:

1. This is the endpoint who receive the request where I want to store the name and id properties in the context.

```
@Get(PATH_GLOBAL)
    suspend fun getGlobal(
        @PathVariable name: String,
        @PathVariable id: String,
        httpRequest: HttpRequest<*>,
    ): HttpResponse<Resource> {
        LoggingContext.logContext(name, id)
        ...
    // invoke repository
        return readOperation.execute(trigger).fold(...)
    }
```

2. Previous endpoints invoke the following function that is stored in another module.

```
override suspend fun readConfiguration(...): {
        logger.trace { "Reading configuration from repository" }
        val entity = configurationDataRepository.findBy(...)
        
        logger.info { "ConfigurationDataRepositoryImpl - readConfiguration4: ${MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()}" }

        withContext(MDCContext()) {
            logger.info { "ConfigurationDataRepositoryImpl - readConfiguration1: ${MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()}" }
        }

        return ...
    }
```

I tried adding `withContext(MDCContext()){...}` but I'm getting a null when calling `getContext()` function with and without `withContext...`

So, how can I set the context to be shared within all the modules?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help :)

Comment: Do you use [MDCContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j/kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j/-m-d-c-context/) while launching the coroutines?

Comment: Hmm no, how could I do that?

Comment: I hoped my link above would provide some clues. ;)
It would make sense to add the current coroutine launching code to the question otherwise.

Comment: No worries, it's okay. I just updated the question. I tried with `withContext(MDCContext())` but honestly I'm not really sure how should I use it 

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution is as easy as adding `withContext(MDCContext())` right after setting the MDC Context to preserve the MDC Context.

So, in my case, I have to wrap my controller with the previous function like that:

```
@Get(PATH_GLOBAL)
    suspend fun getGlobal(
        @PathVariable name: String,
        @PathVariable id: String,
        httpRequest: HttpRequest<*>,
    ): HttpResponse<Resource> {

        LoggingContext.logContext(name, id)
    
        // Add withContext(MDCContext()) right after setting the Context
        return withContext(MDCContext()) {
            ...
            // invoke repository
            readOperation.execute(trigger).fold(...)
        }
    }
```

That works for me!

Comment: This works because now, all the context created within
````return withContext(MDCContext()) {
           
  }
````
Will inherit from this context.

Comment: Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j/kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j/-m-d-c-context/